# Adding elements to List<? extends Superclass>, clarification needed

Tags: java, generics

If `A extends X,` the following declaration is valid

```
    List<? extends X> list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

It seems to be that a list would hold a collection of elements that extend X. As such, `new A()` should qualify.

Yes, it does not. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've almost got it.  `List<? extends X>` means "a list of some type (which I don't actually know) which is a subtype of X (or possibly X itself)".

The problem is if X is, for example, `Number`.  Then `List<? extends X>` means `List<Double>` or `List<Integer>` or some other type, which you've just said *you don't actually know*.  You can't insert any `Number` into a `List<Integer>`.  So, since you don't know the type of the elements of the list, you can't insert *anything* into a `List<? extends Number>`.  You can, however, *retrieve* values from the list, and you are guaranteed that any value contained in the list is *at least* a `Number`.

For more information, read *Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility* in [Effective Java, 2nd Ed.](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC) by Joshua Bloch (a book which every Java programmer should have on their bookshelf).  In particular, this item explains the mnemonic PECS, meaning "producer extends, consumer super", which will help you remember what the `extends` and `super` keywords mean in Java generics and when they should be used.

Answer (score 2):

`List<? extends X>` is no definite type. It means that the variable `list` can be assigned from a range of types, such as `List<A>`, but also `List<B>` (where `B extends X`). If the compiler allowed you to add `new A()` to such a list, you would be adding an `A` to `List<B>`. That would be a failure of type safety.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list reference (variable) that is generics `extends` type. This indicates that the list can hold instances of classes that have `X` as superclass. However, when creating actual instance of the list, you restrict it to hold instances of only class `A`. Doesn't that sound odd?