# Java Generics issue with wildcard, base class and sub class

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have something like:

```
List<? extends BaseClass> a = getMyList();
```

Any of the following two instructions are invalid, and the compiler says that it requires a "? extends BaseClass" as an argument.

```
a.add(new BaseClass());
a.add(new SubClass());
```

I guess the problem is that

How can this be solved?

Comment: which line does compiler point to saying that it requires a `? extends BaseClass`?

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781429/adding-elements-to-list-extends-superclass-clarification-needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler has no way of determining the actual type of the list.

It could be that the type is `SubClass`, in which case you would not be allowed to add a `BaseClass`.
It could even be `SubSubClass`, meaning you couldn't add either `BaseClass` or `SubClass`.

However, this will compile:

```
List<BaseClass> a = getMyList();
a.add(new BaseClass());
a.add(new SubClass());
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `List<? super BaseClass> a` to add stuffs to it. You can only get stuffs from `List<? extends BaseClass> a`.

Take look at this [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/738746).

Answer (score 1):

Usually Java tutorials say you can't add anything to a `List<? extends Something>` because the compiler can't know the effective type in the list.

I found this explanation non intuitive, and also not strictly true, because it pretends the compiler is a smart being, which understands that a `List` is an *ordered container of elements* and prevents you from doing potentially unsafe things. In reality, a compiler is just a program, and it simply obeys some rules.

So, it's best to do some role playing, and thinking like a compiler. You have

```java
interface List<E> {
  void add(E element);
}
```

Note that `<E>` doesn't provide any extra semantic to the compiler, in the sense that it doesn't know that you are defining a *container* type. You could define a `Asdf<Q>`, and for the compiler it doesn't matter, or an `Elephant<W>` and still the same rules apply (and clearly `Elephant` is not a container type, ie you don't add anything to an elephant - I hope...)

So you declare a reference of type `List<? extends Shape>`. The compiler understands something similar

```java
abstract class Unknown extends Shape {}

class ListOfUnknown {
  void add(Unknown element) {}
  Unknown get(int index) {}
}
```

Can you see why you can't add a `Rectangle` to such a list? According to *normal* Java rules, you can supply a `Rectangle` to a method such as `add(Shape)` because their interfaces are assured to be compatible by the subtyping relation.

To be allowed to invoke `add(Unknown)` with an argument of type `Rectangle`, `Rectangle` should be a child of `Unknown`, but `Rectangle` only extends `Shape`, so there is nothing really special to generics here, it's the normal Java rule for type compatibility. To be able to call `add(Unknown)` you'd need a reference to an object of type `Unknown` or equivalent (some class which extends `Unknown`), but as you can see there is no such type defined anywhere, so this eventually prohibits to `add()` anything to this list.

When studying generics, always ask yourself *"Why?"* and never stop at the `List` examples because, even if generics were primary added for collections, they are a *language* feature, so you must understand the semantics they carry on, and not concentrating on the specific implementation of a container type.